# Transfer SoilGrid default projection to a Geographic lat/lon？

Tags: coordinate-system, soilgrids

How do I transfer the [SoilGrid](https://www.isric.org/explore/soilgrids) default projection to a Geographic lat/lon？
Also, is the SoilGrid data only for 2017 and 2019？

Comment: Please add more details on your data source and software.

Answer (score 3):

[SoilGrids WMS services](https://maps.isric.org/) support Geographic lat long projection such as [EPSG:4326](http://www.epsg-registry.org/export.htm?wkt=urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::4326), you just need to request that CRS in your client (for preview).

SoilGrids WCS raster download services, support EPSG:4326, so you can just request the data in that projection.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to [nmtoken's answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/360123/21532), there is also this information in the [FAQ](https://www.isric.org/explore/soilgrids/faq-soilgrids#How_can_I_use_SoilGrids_in_a_different_projection):

> The VRT-mosaics can themselves be easily reprojected using the gdalwarp tool. Considering the size of each mosaic, it is best to require a VRT also as output. For example:
>
> `gdalwarp -t_srs EPSG:3035 -of VRT ./sand_60-100cm_Q0.5.vrt ./sand_60-100cm_Q0.5_3035.vrt`